# Missing 'qedit.dll' in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, directshow

We've found that Windows Server 2008 SP2 doesn't contain QEDIT.DLL.

This 'DirectShow Editing' DLL contained several useful DirectShow filters, namely SampleGrabber, that we had been using.

I found some references to this issue during the Windows Server 2008 beta cycle, but it was supposed to have been added back for release.

Does anyone have any current knowledge of this, and if there are any workarounds other than copying a version from Vista or Win2003?

Comment: Would this http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video/browse_thread/thread/2f508e5944d2111e be one of the references you have found?

Comment: Right, exactly. 

I'd seen this reference to this being added in W2K8 RC1, but I checked a recent W2K8 SP2 production release and qedit.dll wasn't there.  Looks like it never made it through the public release cycle.

[QUOTE: Thank you for reporting back that it is in W2K8 RC1.  Your information was part of the dshow team's case for getting in back in the release]

Answer (score 0):

The SampleGrabber filter is one of the MSDN sample filters. I'm not sure whether all the filters that you need are available as samples though.